# How to get value of atomic variable outside the thread in C++

Tags: c++11, thread-safety, c++14, stdatomic

I have a thread, which keeps running, and this thread receives data from udp network.
when there is no data coming in for lets say 3 seconds, i am setting a atomic variable[STATUS] as 0 and if data started coming again setting atomic variable[STATUS] value is 1

code below:

```
ProtoApiManager.hpp
------------------
// to update computer status
atomic_int STATUS = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(0);

ProtoApiManager.cpp
------------------
_keep_running = true;
_t_bg_tasks = std::thread(&ProtoApiManager::onThreadBgTasks, this);
void main::onThreadBgTasks()
{
    do
    {
        milliseconds currentTime = MiscUtils::getTimeNow();// getting current time
        auto delta = currentTime - _last_status_msg_rx; // assigned when data received
         if (delta.count() > _NAV_COMMS_TIMEOUT) // constant assigned as 3 sec
        {
            std::cout<<"Time out OFFLINE"<<std::endl;
            
            MC_COMPUTER_STATUS = 0;
            // prepareData()
            
        }else{

            std::cout<<"Time out ONLINE"<<std::endl;
            MC_COMPUTER_STATUS = 1;
            // prepareData()
           }

    }
    while(_keep_running);
}

---------------
ProtoApiManager.process.cpp
---------------------------
ProtoApiManager::prepareData()
{
  // preparing data
    hardwareItemStatusMCComputer->set_hardwaretype(10);
    hardwareItemStatusMCComputer->set_hardwarename("MC Computer");
    hardwareItemStatusMCComputer->set_hardwarestatus(STATUS);

  // transmitting to udp
}
---------------------------
```

Now the question is, as thread is keep running in do while, and based on time out i set atomic variable value 0 or 1, i have to call prepareData method outside thread based on atomic variable[STATUS] and set [status] while preparing data

Comment: Which thread do you want `prepareData` to be called on? What is this thread doing when not calling `prepareData` - what does it occupy itself with in between prepareData calls?

Comment: `STATUS` is a global variable so it's visible to all other code in your program.  And it's `atomic` so you can read it from any other thread at any time you want.  So that's the answer to your title question.  (Although you *don't* want to spin-wait on it for long times, like multiple seconds.  So perhaps you should be using a condition variable or some other way for a thread to sleep until notified by another thread.  Like C++20 `wait` perhaps, otherwise I think a mutex + condition variable is the standard way.)

Comment: @Igor, `onThreadBgTasks()` is continuously running, anyway the issue got fixed, i used another variable `_prev_state`  to store my atomic value if the value is same dont call `prepareData()`, if the value if different then call `prepareData()` suggeted by @Peter